# Is assignment of rental unit occupancy for profit legal and practical in Ontario?

Tags: canada, ontario, tenancy-rules

This is in regard to a apartment rental agreement in Ontario, Canada. Because of the recent higher inflation rate, it is likely that if I end my tenancy, the property owner will be able to charge significantly higher rent to the next tenant.  There seems to be an opportunity for myself to profit from finding a new tenant and assigning occupancy to the new tenant.  For no reason other than recent high inflation alone, it seems that I would be able to charge a (September 2022 post-inflation) higher monthly rate and still pay the property owner at my original rate, which in the past has seemed to increase at a low rate in this part of Ontario.   I am not familiar with what kind of non-market forces have determined the slow rate of rent increase in this part of Ontario.  I am planning to relocate abroad for several months.  What are the risks involved in this idea, if it is even legal or practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the raised idea is not legally feasible. A quote...

> If you want to leave your place for a while and then move back in
> later, you might be able to sublet
> to someone else while you are gone. The person who you sublet to is
> called your subtenant.
>
> You cannot charge your subtenant a higher rent than the landlord
> charges you.

Here is a link to the source...

https://stepstojustice.ca/steps/housing-law/sublet-new-tenant/

The source is subtitled "Your guide to law in Ontario".

Comment: Interesting and good to know. Something on which Ontario law differs from the law in most U.S. states.